# Date and value based on conditions

Tags: sql, teradata

I have a scenario where I need to select records based on date and its corresponding column values.

Lets say my table name is TAB1. The key column in TAB1 is NBR. The scenario which need to be implemented is only when  there are two set of records present for the same key and out of two record sets, one record in the column price should have the value 0.

| NBR | DATE | PRICE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 2022-05-09 | 0 |
| 123 | 2023-04-18 | 400 |
| 4001 | 2021-04-18 | 765.12 |
| 4001 | 2023-02-25 | 0 |
| 999 | 2020-01-10 | 873.12 |
| 999 | 2022-11-14 | 88 |

Now in the table we need to do PARTITION by NBR and find the max date , and for the max date if its corresponding PRICE value is 0, then we need to fetch both the records, if not we want to ignore both the records.

Now from the table above, we need to have output as below. The record 123 will be ignored as its max date corresponding price value is not 0. where as the last set 999 will be considered as there are no 0 in the PRICE value.

I am thinking about a solution which can be achieved through partition by/rank instead of using group function as I have more columns there in the row.

Expected output is given below

| NBR | DATE | PRICE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4001 | 2021-04-18 | 765.12 |
| 4001 | 2023-02-25 | 0 |
| 999 | 2020-01-10 | 873.12 |
| 999 | 2022-11-14 | 88 |

Comment: You seem to have a contradiction that you should clear up. In one sentence, you say that you only want pairs where the max date's price is zero. But then you say that 999 should also be reported since there is no zero price.

Comment: I mean the max date and the corresponding value pick need to ve implemented only when pairs with one of the value as 0 present. In other pairs without 0, we don't need this logic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use max and conditional max window functions to check that the row with the max date is the same row with zero price:

```
SELECT NBR, DATE, PRICE
FROM
  (
    SELECT *,
       MAX(DATE) OVER (PARTITION BY NBR) mx_dt,
       MAX(CASE WHEN PRICE = 0 THEN DATE END) OVER (PARTITION BY NBR) dt_zero_pr
    FROM table_name
  ) T
WHERE mx_dt = dt_zero_pr OR dt_zero_pr IS NULL
ORDER BY NBR, DATE
```

And if you want to strict this to only `NBR` values with two rows only, as you said *(The scenario which I need to be implemented is only when there are two sets of records present for the same key)*, we can use the count window function with this query:

```
SELECT NBR, DATE, PRICE
FROM
  (
    SELECT *,
       MAX(DATE) OVER (PARTITION BY NBR) mx_dt,
       MAX(CASE WHEN PRICE = 0 THEN DATE END) OVER (PARTITION BY NBR) dt_zero_pr,
       COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY NBR) cnt
    FROM table_name
  ) T
WHERE ((mx_dt = dt_zero_pr OR dt_zero_pr IS NULL) AND cnt = 2) 
  OR cnt <> 2
ORDER BY NBR, DATE
```

[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/cGwMCQnR)

Answer (score 0):

See example (tested on SQL Server)

```
select * 
from 
  (select *
    ,sum(case when price=0 then 1 else 0 end)over(partition by nbr) hasZero
    ,case when first_value(price)over(partition by nbr order by [date] desc) =0 then 1
     else 0 
     end lastIsZero
   from tab1
  )t
where hasZero=0 or lastIsZero=1
```

Result

| NBR | DATE | PRICE | hasZero | lastIsZero |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 999 | 2022-11-14 | 88 | 0 | 0 |
| 999 | 2020-01-10 | 873.12 | 0 | 0 |
| 4001 | 2023-02-25 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 4001 | 2021-04-18 | 765.12 | 1 | 1 |